# Why does MinGW-w64 floating-point precision depend on winpthreads version?

Tags: c++, g++, pthreads, precision, mingw-w64

I use the MinGW-w64 g++ compilers 10.2 and 10.3. I have built both myself using https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds.

There is an oddity with g++ on Windows: the main thread of an application will do floating-point operations with double precision, but additional threads will do them with extended precision. This can be reproduced with this small program ("Test.cpp"):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

std::string getResult()
{
    std::cout << "Thread id: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    std::string result = "Result:\n";

    double a, b, c;
    int i;
    for (i = 0, a = 1.0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        a *= 1.00000001;
        b = sqrt(a);
        c = pow(a, 0.5);
        if (std::abs(b - c) < 1.0e-50)
            continue;
        result += std::string("a: ") + std::to_string(a) + " - Numbers differ.\n";
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::string string1 = getResult();

    std::future<std::string> result = std::async(std::launch::async, getResult);

    std::string string2 = result.get();

    if (string1 != string2)
    {
        std::cout << "The results are different." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The results are the same." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling it with optimization (!) like this:
`g++ -o Test.exe Test.cpp -O2`
and executing it, the output is:

```
C:\...Path...>Test.exe
Thread id: 1
Thread id: 2
The results are different.
```

For me this is a major problem. For security reasons I expect all numerical results to be always the same - no matter whether they are executed asynchronously on different threads or sequentially on the main thread. Otherwise for example my unit tests might fail depending on the execution conditions.

I had posted a message to the MinGW-w64 mailing list: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/message/34896011/. As result of the discussion thread, my solution was to link the object file `CRT_fp8.o`.

Modifying the compilation command to `g++ -o Test.exe Test.cpp -O2 c:\mingw-w64-10.2\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\CRT_fp8.o` (paths might need adjustment) results in all threads doing floating-point operations with double precision. Now the results from different threads won't differ anymore.

This has been a fine solution for me for several years. However, a few weeks ago while playing with different compiler versions I have discovered that the solution with linking to `CRT_fp8.o` is not as stable as I had expected.

When compiling with g++ 10.2 and then changing the path to contain the "bin" folder of g++ 10.3, the threads will again produce different results. I can reproduce it here with these console commands:

```
set path=c:\mingw-w64-10.2\mingw64\bin
g++ -o Test.exe Test.cpp -O2 c:\mingw-w64-10.2\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\CRT_fp8.o

C:\...Path...>Test.exe
Thread id: 1
Thread id: 2
The results are the same.

set path=c:\mingw-w64-10.3\mingw64\bin

C:\...Path...>Test.exe
Thread id: 1
Thread id: 2
The results are different.
```

This is again really bad! If the user of my application by chance has the wrong libraries in his path, he will get different results!!! :-(

Another surprise is that the workaround with `CRT_fp8.o` seems to be unnecessary when using only g++ 10.3:

```
set path=c:\mingw-w64-10.3\mingw64\bin
g++ -o Test.exe Test.cpp -O2

C:\...Path...>Test.exe
Thread id: 1
Thread id: 2
The results are the same.
```

I have played with the shared libraries in the MinGW-w64 "bin" folder and found out that the behaviour depends on the file "libwinpthread-1.dll". If I copy the file from the g++ 10.2 installation to the g++ 10.3 installation overwriting its own shared library, then the behaviour is again as it has been the last years: linking to CRT_fp8.o is needed to get double precision on all threads.

Is this a bug? A MinGW-w64 bug? Or a libwinpthreads bug? Or a feature? Is my workaround for consistent precision outdated? What is the new workaround?

Comment: You code nowhere prints `The results are different.` - are you sure you are running this code? `std::to_string(a) ` Please instead use an `stringstream`  and output the number with `std::hexfloat` for inspection.

Comment: "For security reasons I expect all numerical results to be always the same ". That's bad security or bad math, or possibly both. Do not make that assumption.

Comment: Isn't the idiomatic approach here to use a reasonable standard-deviation when comparing for equality?

Comment: @KamilCuk I am sorry, I have changed the test code while playing with different settings. Now the code in the question is what I have actually used.

Comment: @super You are right, but that is not the point here. I have changed the code to remove a possible source of distraction.

Comment: @MSalters But in my code I execute the **same** function twice, one time in the main thread and one time in another thread. Do you still consider it a bad assumption, that the **same** function (which doesn't depend on input) should return identical results?!?!

Comment: @BenjaminBihler: Oh, it might return the same result. We can't tell from this code example whether the problem is in `sqrt`, `pow` or even `==`. Is that a 64 bit `==` or an 80 bit `==` ?

Comment: @MSalters With "same function" I meant my own function `getResult()`. You are right that `sqrt` and/or `pow` or even the equality operator work different when executed on different threads, but this is exactly the problem I want to solve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described behaviour is a MinGW-w64 bug. Different to the description in the original post, it has nothing to do with g++ versions, but only with MinGW-w64 versions. It has been reported here: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/897/.

What does that mean?

With mingw-builds the MinGW version can be specified when building the compiler. Version 7 is safe, version 8 introduces the described error. So version 7 can be used as a workaround.

Comment: I hope you find a satisfactory resolution, but as an answer to the question this seems a bit under-supported.  That is, I have no reason to dispute that the behavior is associated with MinGW-w64 version as opposed to compiler version, but you have linked to your own, new and as-yet unaccepted bug report.  You may be quite right in calling it a bug in mingw-w64, but that does not seem well established yet.

Comment: @JohnBollinger The conversation linked in the bug report is my "proof". I have built gcc 10.2 and 10.3 with different MinGW-w64 versions and obviously version 8 introduces a behaviour that differs from the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you compare the results of `sqrt(x)` and `pow(x,0.5)` on one compiler, the results can differ. But the compiler might reasonably inline `sqrt`, which is obviously simpler than `pow`. That would mean that if you compile with GCC 10.2 you get an inlined `sqrt` but when you then run it with a 10.3 runtime DLL. you link to that `pow`, so you're not even comparing identical versions.

What `CRT_fp8.o` does is provide an alternative `_fpreset` function to reset the FPU to an alternative default state - not the 80 bits MinGW default, but 64 bits precision.

Note that MinGW is an impressive attempt to shoehorn GCC into Windows. But GCC is very much a Stallman project in its origins, with a strong Unix assumption.

In the end, the problem might be best avoided altogether by moving to x64. This should use SSE2 for all FP math. And since SSE2 is never 80 bits, you always get 64 bits.

Comment: What do you mean with "moving to x64"?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler: The 80 bits precision is pretty unique to 80x87 FPU's, which are used in x86 32 bits code. But 32 bits x86 CPU's are virtually extinct nowadays. Every Intel Pentium, Celeron or Core, and each AMD support 64 bits "x64" mode. And in this mode, you have at least the SSE2 vector FPU.

Comment: Well, I use the default target architecture. Is your proposal to mess around with the target CPU type? This would be a rather strong intervention... the default architecture is `-march=nocona` and `-mtune=core2` here.

Comment: @BenjaminBihler: Ah, that's a very special case. Nocona is a rare, old Intel Atom chip which lacks SSE2. `-march=core2` is the original Intel Core2 from 2006.

Comment: If I have understood it correctly, this setting is done by MinGW-w64 or gcc projects to have a compromise between the ability to be run on as many CPUs as possible and optimization. I hesitate to change that, since I guess that someone had a good reason for making this decision...?

Comment: @BenjaminBihler: Nocona is not a compromise at all. It means "literally every x64, even the very rare ones without SSE2". And mtune=core2 means "tune for a CPU from 2006", so that will be quite sub-optimal on a CPU from 2009 or 2012, let alone one from 2021. There _was_ a good reason for that decision, but it doesn't make sense anymore. Do you even have a Nocona or Core 2 CPU to test it on?

Comment: According to this post from 2017 it seems to still have been a valid decision four years ago: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/discussion/723797/thread/9b9401aa/. But anyhow, I would prefer to have consistent floating-point operation precision without changing the target architecture. If that isn't possible, maybe I will consider such modifications.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231932/discussion-between-msalters-and-benjamin-bihler).

Answer (score 0):

I beleive that sqrt(x) and pow(x, 0.5) are not exactly the same function. It should be, but I guess the pow(x, 0.5) uses logarithmics for all its calculations.
Therefore av small error might be introduced. Besides that the decimal value 0.5 might be converted to its binary representation according IEEE 754, and might not be exactly identical to the value of 0.5.

Dont remember all these pitfalls when using these functions, but they are difficult to track.
Regards Sv B

Comment: Thank you, but that is not the point here. (My code is grown code and might be misleading.) The point is that the **same** function `getResult()` gives different results depending on the thread in which it has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - Maybe that the task scheduler is the culprit here ? When a child thread is put to sleep by the task scheduler, it might copying the 80-bits FPU registers to 64 bit doubles ?
Therefore it will loose some precision in the calculations.
Besides that - the code

```
for (i = 0, a = 1.0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        a *= 1.00000001;
        b = sqrt(a);
        c = pow(a, 0.5);
    }
```

is bad programming practice, it increases error propagation in all steps.

Since the loops runs 10 000 000 times, error propagation might be so big that
the resulting values are dead wrong.
Read the book "Numerical Recipes in C" and many of the floating points calculations are described there also in the sense that keeping the calculation errors as low as possible. The 80-bits FPUs was designed to accommodate for scientific calculations having 10 significant digits that are correct, I guess.

Hard to remember now, since that many years ago now, I was into real  numbercrunching businesses.
Interesting problem though. But you should consider redesigning your code that it doesnt need that many iterations.

Or you might use 128-bit floats, ie "long double". Long double will vastly lower error propagation.
But I doubt that sqrt(x) and pow(x, 0.5) will produce the exact same result even with long doubles.

Most of these functions expands into infinite mathematical series, and are limited by the (limited) design of the FPUs.

Some graphics libraries can in fact run faster if they are relying on table-lookup for sinus and cosinus values. Memory footprint arent any problem any longer nowadays. And you will save some CPU/FPU-cycles on each calculation step.
Regards,
Sv B

Answer (score 0):

You are probably right about that the shown error in runtime of your code is a bug. If you can repeat the bug consistently it must be a bug.
Its the prime definition of a bug, that it can be repeated in a consistent manner.

However, we dont know if the child thread is optimized in such a way that calculation errors increases.

But according to university courses and Numerical Recipes in C its always the programmer to blame when writing code calculations that allows too much error propagation. Error propagation is always a fact in all kinds of math,  when using integers or especially float calculations.

You are right that IEEE 754 should behave consistently when moving from one machine to another, or the main thread to the child thread.

Why should the programmer be  blamed ?
Well its the only one who can estimate the calculation errors and write a code that is limiting these in every single step.
These steps are repeated 10 000 000 times, which I guess is  way too many.

You can recalculate the same loops with long doubles or _float128 instead and you might get an estimate of how big the error is, when running on doubles instead.
And compare long doubles or _float128  to these doubles.

The default in C is always truncating the values, no "scientific
rounding" are done. Such "rounding" is not part of the C standards.

Hope that you can submit the bug in such a way that other programmers
can analyze it accordingly ?

Interestingly enough is that in computer science, ther have been attempts to design FPUs that keeps track of the estimated error  in each calculation. But will of course be very complicated to construct. Much easier to redo the calculations with a  higher precision settings, like the long doubles,
or better _float128.
_float128 is the binary float equivalent of two doubles, and could hold 34 significant decimal digits :-)

There is no such thing like a free lunch ?
Regards,
Sven B